# How to animate view from bottom to top in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have listView in which i am adding item from bottom.
I want to animate added item and rest of list view should slide up.
Animation effect should be from bottom to top.
I have tried translate animation but it slides only added item.
Thanks

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526288/how-to-make-a-buttons-bar-slide-in-from-bottom-upon-clicking-checkbox-in-listvie)

Answer (score 19):

```
public static void slideToBottom(View view){
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,view.getHeight());
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public static void slideToTop(View view){
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,view.getHeight(),0);
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this LIB it may helps you

> http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/?ref=app

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the listView background to white

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).